SQL Grouping is returning wrong (inflated) aggregated value for a column
I have 3 tables: TABLE1, TABLE2 and TABLE3.
TABLE1 and TABLE2 have 1 row each, while TABLE3 has 3 rows. Both TABLE2 and TABLE3 have a foreign key to TABLE1.
I am seeing that if I join all 3 of them and then group the result, then a value in TABLE2 is shown 3 times the real value. Can somebody explain the reason?
I tried this:
declare @TABLE1 table (table1_id int);
declare @TABLE2 table (table2_id int, table1_id int, earning money);
declare @TABLE3 table (table3_id int, table1_id int);

insert into @TABLE1 values (1);
insert into @TABLE2 values (49, 1, 10000);
insert into @TABLE3 values (991, 1);
insert into @TABLE3 values (992, 1);
insert into @TABLE3 values (993, 1);

select 
    T1.table1_id, SUM(T2.earning) 'earning'
from 
    @TABLE1 T1
inner join 
    @TABLE2 T2 on T2.table1_id = T1.table1_id
inner join 
    @TABLE3 T3 on T3.table1_id = T1.table1_id
group by 
    T1.table1_id;

When I run that query, it returns 1 row with 2 columns (table1_id and earning).



table1_id
earning




1
30000.00



I was expecting the value of earning column will be 10000.00 but I am getting 30000.00. What is the reason?

Looks right to me. Unaggregated you have 3 rows (db<>fiddle) with the value 10,000 each and the SUM of 3 10000 values is 30000. Why are you expecting otherwise?

Remove the group by and check the results. Joining a child table with 3 rows, creates, surprise surprise, 3 rows.

Your example doesn't explain why you even need a table3... so including that would clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Your query appears to involve multiple independent one-to-many joins, which is a common source of data duplication and inflated aggregated results. You need to separate out one or both into subqueries, CTEs or cross applys.

Thanks guys for your answer. Makes perfect sense. I will have to use subqueries to accomplish my goal as @TN recommend.

What is the purpose of using Table3 in this query?

@JoelCoehoorn - I expect the real query the OP is working on is much more involved, and the Table3 reference was a necessary part after the OP did a nice job reducing the problem to a minimum reproducible example.

Your query appears to involve multiple independent one-to-many joins, which is a common source of data duplication and inflated aggregated results. You need to separate out one or both into subqueries, CTEs or CROSS APPLYs.
Fixed using CROSS APPLY:
select 
    T1.table1_id, CA1.Earning, CA2.T3Count
from 
    TABLE1 T1
cross apply (
    select SUM(earning) AS Earning
    from TABLE2 T2
    where T2.table1_id = T1.table1_id
) CA1
cross apply (
    select COUNT(*) AS T3Count
    from TABLE3 T3
    where T3.table1_id = T1.table1_id
) CA2

Fixed using subqueries:
select 
    T1.table1_id, SS1.Earning, SS2.T3Count
from 
    TABLE1 T1
inner join (
    select T2.table1_id, SUM(earning) AS Earning
    from TABLE2 T2
    group by T2.table1_id
) SS1 on SS1.table1_id = T1.table1_id
inner join (
    select T3.table1_id, COUNT(*) AS T3Count
    from TABLE3 T3
    group by T3.table1_id
) SS2 on SS2.table1_id = T1.table1_id

I added the T3Count column to give the TABLE3 reference some meaning.
Uncorrected results (with some extra test data):



table1_id
Earning
T3Count




1
30000.0000
3


2
35000.0000
10



Corrected results:



table1_id
Earning
T3Count




1
10000.0000
3


2
7000.0000
5



See this db<>fiddle for a demo with some extra test data.
In some situations where the joined data might have no matches, you may need to change the cross apply to an outer apply and the inner join to a left join.

Note that although CROSS APPLY normally gets you an inner join style, in this case you are using a scalar aggregate (no GROUP BY) so it comes out to a left-join, because scalar aggregates always return exactly one row. Use GROUP BY () or GROUP BY TheCorrelationColumn inside the subquery to get an inner join. See https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html

Good point. Yes, that is true for the above usage. I thought about that when I did the writeup, but decided to mention it anyway (without going into too much detail) in case the actual real-world query might involve something other than a scalar aggregation.
